# Path fixing in Codecov: some files work others not

Tags: code-coverage, github-actions, gcov, codecov

I have a project to casually play around with C++ test coverage. (https://github.com/adomasbaliuka/test_repository, question refers to commits 58e2802f76e8eb7819209c9d518b0ffe76690d15 and ca36a4fd0e38bc47204a155614c498936d43dc90)

The question concerns GitHub and Codecov.io, so maybe I should ask their support, but StackOverflor has tags for these things, so I assume it's OK.

**The coverage with codecov.io is working** (https://app.codecov.io/gh/adomasbaliuka/test_repository). **However, I would like to see the actual source code and line coverage to also test this feature of codecov.io. It works fine on one of my files** (`test/test_main.cpp`) **but I can't get it to work on the other source file** (`src/version/version.cpp`), even though codecov.io correctly displays both paths and the paths inside the uploaded `codecov.xml` file (which I print to console in my CI runs, so they can also be viewed in the GitHub Actions) look conceptually exactly the same:

(`codecov.xml` file contents:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage SYSTEM 'http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd'>
<coverage line-rate="0.7613636363636364" branch-rate="0.33962264150943394" lines-covered="67" lines-valid="88" branches-covered="36" branches-valid="106" complexity="0.0" timestamp="1631309448" version="gcovr 4.2">
  <sources>
    <source>../../</source>
  </sources>
  <packages>
    <package name="test_repository.build._deps.googletest-src.googletest.include.gtest" line-rate="0.2857142857142857" branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0">
      <classes>
        <class name="gtest_h" filename="test_repository/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h" line-rate="0.2857142857142857" branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods/>
          <lines>
            <line number="427" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="435" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="440" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="441" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="522" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="2489" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="2490" hits="2" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
      </classes>
    </package>
    <package name="test_repository.build._deps.googletest-src.googletest.include.gtest.internal" line-rate="0.85" branch-rate="0.2" complexity="0.0">
      <classes>
        <class name="gtest-internal_h" filename="test_repository/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h" line-rate="0.8947368421052632" branch-rate="0.2" complexity="0.0">
          <methods/>
          <lines>
            <line number="454" hits="8" branch="false"/>
            <line number="461" hits="4" branch="false"/>
            <line number="472" hits="4" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="493" hits="4" branch="false"/>
            <line number="494" hits="4" branch="false"/>
            <line number="506" hits="16" branch="false"/>
            <line number="508" hits="16" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="521" hits="4" branch="false"/>
            <line number="525" hits="4" branch="false"/>
            <line number="527" hits="4" branch="false"/>
            <line number="529" hits="4" branch="true" condition-coverage="33% (2/6)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="33%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="532" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/10)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="534" hits="4" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="542" hits="4" branch="false"/>
            <line number="546" hits="4" branch="false"/>
            <line number="548" hits="4" branch="false"/>
            <line number="550" hits="4" branch="true" condition-coverage="33% (2/6)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="33%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="553" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/10)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="555" hits="4" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
          </lines>
        </class>
        <class name="gtest-port_h" filename="test_repository/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h" line-rate="0.0" branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods/>
          <lines>
            <line number="974" hits="0" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
      </classes>
    </package>
    <package name="test_repository.test_repository.src.version" line-rate="0.717391304347826" branch-rate="0.4107142857142857" complexity="0.0">
      <classes>
        <class name="version_cpp" filename="test_repository/test_repository/src/version/version.cpp" line-rate="0.717391304347826" branch-rate="0.4107142857142857" complexity="0.0">
          <methods/>
          <lines>
            <line number="22" hits="3" branch="false"/>
            <line number="24" hits="6" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="25" hits="6" branch="false"/>
            <line number="26" hits="3" branch="false"/>
            <line number="27" hits="6" branch="true" condition-coverage="66% (4/6)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="66%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="28" hits="3" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="30" hits="6" branch="false"/>
            <line number="34" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="36" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="37" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="40" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="42" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="43" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="46" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="48" hits="2" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="50" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="52" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="56" hits="2" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="58" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="59" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="62" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="63" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="64" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="66" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="71" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="73" hits="2" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="75" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="77" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="81" hits="2" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="83" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="84" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="87" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="89" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="90" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="92" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="97" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="99" hits="2" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="101" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="103" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="107" hits="2" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="109" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="110" hits="1" branch="false"/>
            <line number="113" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="115" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="116" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="118" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
          </lines>
        </class>
      </classes>
    </package>
    <package name="test_repository.test_repository.tests" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="0.5" complexity="0.0">
      <classes>
        <class name="test_main_cpp" filename="test_repository/test_repository/tests/test_main.cpp" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="0.5" complexity="0.0">
          <methods/>
          <lines>
            <line number="12" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="14" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="15" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="18" hits="8" branch="false"/>
            <line number="21" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="22" hits="2" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (1/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="23" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="24" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="26" hits="8" branch="false"/>
            <line number="27" hits="2" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (2/4)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="28" hits="2" branch="true" condition-coverage="50% (2/4)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="50%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="30" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="31" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="32" hits="2" branch="false"/>
            <line number="33" hits="2" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
      </classes>
    </package>
  </packages>
</coverage>
```

In particular, the paths of the files inside this `xml` are `test_repository/tests/test_main.cpp` and `test_repository/src/version/version.cpp`. I totally don't understand the problem or difference that codecov.io could possibly see there.

Inside codecov.io, clicking on the file `src/version/version.cpp` gives me an error

> GitHub API: Not Found

I tried doing some "path fixing", as suggested by codecov.io, which means including a top level file `codecov.yml`. I put inside this file

```yaml
fixes:
   - "test_repository/::"
```

which I assume replaces the name of the repository by "nothing" in the paths. The result of this was that the first file still worked, while for the second file the error message became

> Well this is embarassing, looks like we had an error.

I don't depend on having this feature work on all my files, but this behaviour (difference between the files) is just bizarre to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom from Codecov here. I think you might need to do

```
fixes:
  - "::/test_repository"
```

But I'll be totally honest, I don't think you need path fixes at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! I tried this and as a result both files stopped working with the error "GitHub API: Not Found ".

Comment: Gah! I see that. And if you don't have any fixes?

Comment: Tried that, too, initially, as described in my question. Those commits are also still on codecov. In that case, one file works and the other has the "GitHub API: Not Found".

Comment: I just fixed an error in my question which may be relevant. The problematic file is at `src/version/version.cpp` (I had written `src/version.cpp` by mistake), s.t. the folder name is similar to the file name. I can't imagine how this could cause the error but will try some variations of this tomorrow...

Comment: Got it, I think you got it right in [this commit](https://codecov.io/gh/adomasbaliuka/test_repository/src/58e2802f76e8eb7819209c9d518b0ffe76690d15), but you might need to install the [Codecov app integration](https://github.com/apps/codecov)

Comment: In that commit (the link is not working by the way, I copied the commit hash from the url) one file works and the other does not. It is the commit with the `codecov.yml` file as described in the question. I'll look at the app integration, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, I realized why the error ocurred. It was due to the file in question not being in the repository at all. In fact, it is configured automatically by CMake during the build process. Again, very sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the problematic file isn't even in the repository at all. It is instead generated ("configured") by CMake, in order to include the current version, which is extracted from git information.

In hindsight my question was really stupid and I am very sorry to have wasted anyone's time. Unfortunately, there probably isn't anything in this question that you can learn from.

Comment: No worries, it happens! I should have realized that as well. Thanks for responding back with the issue. Is there anything else you need?

Comment: Everything looks great, thanks a lot for your help!